# implementting right click event on google maps marker

Tags: ipad, google-maps, right-click

Need to have right-click event on google map marker.

Is there any javascript plugin for web application to implement the same?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144374/longpress-longclick-event-support-plugin-in-jquery

Implement long press to trigger right click.

Comment: will it work on google map marker object?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the long press event in place of right click

Like this

**HTML:**

```
<a href="" title="">Long press</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("a").mouseup(function(){
  // Clear timeout
  return false;
}).mousedown(function(){
  // Set timeout
  return false; 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to apply a **rightclick** event to the marker and when right clicked it will pass the **MouseEvent** to a specified callback. Like this:

```
marker.addListener("rightclick", callback(event));
```

Here is the [MouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MouseEvent) documentation and here is the [Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker) object documentation.